# Sharing login between OAuth 2 and Session Authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth-2.0, laravel-backpack

At the moment we have a React application that uses OAuth2 for authentication and a second application that uses Laravel with Backpack. Is there any viable way to share the login between the two apps, as they are just two parts of the same system.

**[UPDATED]**

Additional information: both the Laravel project using session auth (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication) and the React application using OAuth 2 (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport) will be running in the same browser. The intention is to make a seamless transition between these two parts.

Both Session auth and OAuth are using the default implementations provided by Laravel.

Short story behind the requirement - we have a system where the user can order products, but some of the users are also sellers. We have the Laravel project as the front-end shop part and the React app as a panel for moderating the products that you sell.

Comment: Does both applications runs on browser ? If so do they use same browser ?

Comment: Also it's required to know what you mean by Ouath 2 and Basic Auth. and how you use them in each app

Comment: @KavinduDodanduwa, thank you for the guidelines. I have updated my question.